# why did one value change but the second value did not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = [ 1, 2 ]
b = a
a.append(3)
print(b) # shows [ 1 2 3 ] which means b changed

c = 4
d = c
c = 8
print(d) # shows 4 which means d did not change
```

Why did b change, but d did not? the .append changed the value stored in b, but c = 8 did not change the value in d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about if the object you assign is `mutable` or `immutable`.

Simply put - mutable objects can be changed after they are created, immutable objects can't.

Considering you have a variable `a` that is assigned to an object, when you point a new variable to the `a` variable, there are two possibilities:

1. If an object is `mutable` -> you will just point to the same object with your new variable
2. If an object is `immutable` -> you will assign a new object to your new variable.

Your first case:

- First you create a list `a`, which is a mutable object
- Then you point with a second variable `b` to the same list object.
- When you change value, you just change a mutable object, to which both variables are pointing.

In second case:

- First you assign a variable `c` to an immutable `int=4` object.
- Then you assign it to the second variable `d`.
- And what happens next, is that you assign a new immutable `int=8` object to the variable `c`.

There is plenty of articles about what does it mean that an object is mutable, for example: https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Comment: The answer with most upvotes was still confusing but you gave me an easy answer with also a very reasonable explanation of "why"

Answer (score 6):

The two examples are not equivalent.

By doing `b = a` you are telling `b` to point to the same list that `a` points to. If you change the list through `a` it will be changed even if introspected through `b`. There is only ever one list in memory.

In the second example you are doing `d = c` which tells `d` to point to the same integer that `c` does, but then you are telling `c` to point to another integer. `d` does not know about it, and it is still pointing to the same integer that `c` used to point to.

The equivalent example using lists to your second example will be

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
a = []
print(a)
# []
print(b)
# [1, 2]
```

Check these visualizations:

[Your first example](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B%201,%202%20%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%0Aa.append%283%29%0Aprint%28b%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[Your second example](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=c%20%3D%204%0Ad%20%3D%20c%0Ac%20%3D%208%0Aprint%28d%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[My example](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1,%202%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Aprint%28a%29%0A%23%20%5B%5D%0Aprint%28b%29%0A%23%20%5B1,%202%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @DeepSpace is a good explanation.

If you want to check if two variables are pointing to the same memory location you can use `is` operator and to print them use `id`.

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=a
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a),id(b)
(2865413182600, 2865413182600)
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a,b,id(a),id(b)
([1,2,2],[1,2,2],2865413182600, 2865413182600)
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[1,2]
>>> a is b
False
```